# Identify this piece by Fauré that starts on a D♭?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

Please see the 29:24 juncture [here](https://youtu.be/YnUfQMkGyv8?t=29m24s). The left hand plays solid chords, while the right broken triads.

Comment: It sounds like it could be from his [Nocturne No. 6 in D flat, Op. 63](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s5E7ry50vs).

Comment: It's a beautiful piece and it sounds very familiar.  It doesn't seem to be any of the [Faure piano pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_music_of_Gabriel_Faur%C3%A9) *in* D flat, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Fauré's [Cantique de Jean Racine Op. 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jliWPm6hoU).

I was wrong to have expected the piece to be by solo piano when it's actually usually performed with a choir.

Comment: Great find --it looks like most of the versions online are performed with organ or full orchestra, which sounds entirely different then with the piano accompaniment --that made it especially difficult to locate.